# DirectX 11 changing the pixel bytes

Tags: visual-c++, directx-11

Followed this guide [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Sprites-and-textures)

I am tasked with "using map and unmap methods to draw a line across the screen by setting pixel byte data to rgb red values".

I have the sprite and background displaying but have no idea how to get the data.

I also tried doing this:

```
//Create device
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc;
ZeroMemory(&desc, sizeof(D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC));
desc.Width = 500;
desc.Height = 300;
desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
desc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
desc.MiscFlags = 0;
desc.MipLevels = 1;
desc.ArraySize = 1;
desc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
desc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;


m_d3dDevice->CreateTexture2D(&desc, nullptr, &texture);
m_d3dDevice->CreateShaderResourceView(texture, 0, &textureView);

// Render
D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mapped;
m_d3dContext->Map(texture, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &mapped);

data = (BYTE*)mapped.pData;
rows = (BYTE)sizeof(data);

std::cout << "hi" << std::endl;
m_d3dContext->Unmap(texture, 0);
```

Problem is that in that case data array is size 0 but has a pointer. This means that I am pointing to a texture that doesn't have any data or am I not getting this?

Edit:
currently I found

```
D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC desc;
m_background->GetDesc(&desc);
desc.Buffer; // buffer
```

Answer (score 1):

I felt the need to create an Answer for this as when I searched for how do this. This question pops up first and the supplied answer didn't really solve the problem for me and wasn't quite the way I wanted to do it anyways...

In my program I have a method as below.

```
void ContentLoader::WritePixelsToShaderIndex(uint32_t *data, int width, int height, int index)
{
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc = {};
    desc.Width = width;
    desc.Height = height;
    desc.MipLevels = 1;
    desc.ArraySize = 1;
    desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    desc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    desc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
    desc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    desc.MiscFlags = 0;

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA initData;
    initData.pSysMem = data;
    initData.SysMemPitch = width * 4;
    initData.SysMemSlicePitch = width * height * 4;

    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> tex;

    Engine::device->CreateTexture2D(&desc, &initData, tex.GetAddressOf());

    Engine::device->CreateShaderResourceView(tex.Get(), NULL, ContentLoader::GetTextureAddress(index));
}
```

Then using the below code I tested drawing a Blue Square with a White Line. And it works perfectly fine. The issue I was getting was setting the System Mem Slice and Mem Pitch after looking in the WICTextureLoader class I was able to figure out how the data is stored. So it appears the

**MemPitch = The Row's Size in Bytes.
MemSlice = The Total Image Pixels Size In Bytes.**

```
const int WIDTH = 200;
const int HEIGHT = 200;
const uint32_t RED = 255 | (0 << 8) | (0 << 16) | (255 << 24);
const uint32_t WHITE = 255 | (255 << 8) | (255 << 16) | (255 << 24);
const uint32_t BLUE = 0 | (0 << 8) | (255 << 16) | (255 << 24);
uint32_t *buffer = new uint32_t[WIDTH * HEIGHT];
bool flip = false;
for (int X = 0; X < WIDTH; ++X)
{
    for (int Y = 0; Y < HEIGHT; ++Y)
    {
        int pixel = X + Y * WIDTH;
        buffer[pixel] = flip ? BLUE : WHITE;
    }
    flip = true;
}

WritePixelsToShaderIndex(buffer, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 3);
delete [] buffer;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, most of those functions return `HRESULT` values that you are ignoring. That's not safe as you will miss important errors that invalidate the remaining code. You can use `if(FAILED(...))` if you want, or you can use [ThrowIfFailed](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ThrowIfFailed), but you can't just ignore the return value in a functioning app.

```
HRESULT hr = m_d3dDevice->CreateTexture2D(&desc, nullptr, &texture);
if (FAILED(hr))
    // error!
hr = m_d3dDevice->CreateShaderResourceView(texture, 0, &textureView);
if (FAILED(hr))
    // error!

// Render
D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mapped;
hr = m_d3dContext->Map(texture, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &mapped);
if (FAILED(hr))
    // error!
```

Second, you should enable the [Debug Device](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/11/30/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks.aspx) and look for diagnostic output which will likely point you to the reason for the failure.

`sizeof(data)` is always going to be 4 or 8 since data is a `BYTE*` i.e. the size of a pointer. It has nothing to do with the size of your data array. The locked buffer pointed to by `mapped.pData` is going to be `mapped.RowPitch * desc.Height` bytes in size.

You have to copy your pixel data into it row-by-row. Depending on the format and other factors, `mapped.RowPitch` is not necessarily going to be `4 * desc.Width`--4 bytes per pixel is because you are using a format of `DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM`. It should be at least that big, but it could be bigger to align the overall size.

This is pseudo-code and not necessarily an efficient way to do it, but:

```
for(UINT y = 0; y < desc.Height; ++y )
{
    for(UINT x = 0; x < desc.Width; ++x )
    {
        // Find the memory location of the pixel at (x,y)
        int pixel = y * mapped.RowPitch + (x*4)
        BYTE* blue = data[pixel];
        BYTE* green = data[pixel] + 1;
        BYTE* red = data[pixel] + 2;
        BYTE* alpha = data[pixel] + 3;

        *blue = /* value between 0 and 255 */;
        *green = /* value between 0 and 255 */;
        *red = /* value between 0 and 255 */;
        *alpha = /* value between 0 and 255 */;
    }
}
```

You should take a look at [DirectXTex](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex) which does a lot of this kind of row-by-row processing.